# SSD RAID card in Mac Pro (Mid 2012) 5,1

Tags: startup, ssd, mac-pro

question with two parts:

Is there any card that has PCIe x4 with AHCI interface (to be bootable on MAC Pro) that takes two M.2 SSD cards?

And if teher is does it matter if the SSDs (if the card allows) **AHCI** or **NVMe** as it will be in RAID and the RAID chipset will be **AHCI**?

[image]

hope my question is clear

Comment: Do you mean something like this - [Hybrid RAID Controller PCI Express Card](https://amzn.to/2rrE0Tf)?  You will have to inquire about support for macOS, but I don't see why it would be an issue since it will "appear" to the OS as a PCIe SSD.

Comment: yes something like this, but this one is old it uses the slow SATA interface, I was thinking of a faster one to reach faster than the SATA like the AHCI or NVMe SSD drives.

Comment: this one is very close [Angelbird Wings PX1 PCIe x4 M.2 Adapter](https://www.angelbird.com/prod/wings-px1-1117/)